# Limit height of a cell inside a table for an email in the Outlook desktop app

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

How can I limit the height of a table cell for an email in the Outlook desktop app?

It displays well in the browser.
In the Outlook desktop app, all the text by the identifier `#some-text` increases the length of the cell.

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/ArtfulLee/zxg6msyt/

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Template</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border-spacing: 0;
            mso-cellspacing: 0;
            mso-padding-alt: 0;
        }

        td {
            padding: 0;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    </style>

    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <style type="text/css">
      table {border-collapse: collapse !important;}
    </style>
  <![endif]-->

    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  <xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      <o:AllowPNG/>
      <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
  </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  </xml>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body style="Margin:0;padding:0;min-width:100%;background-color:#e5e5e5;">

    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      <style type="text/css">
         body {background-color: #e5e5e5!important;}
         body, table, td, p, a {font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica!important;}
      </style>
   <![endif]-->

    <center style="width: 100%;table-layout:fixed;background-color: #e5e5e5;padding-top: 40px;padding-bottom: 40px;">
        <div style="max-width: 800px;background-color: #006c5e;">


            <!-- <div
                style="font-size: 0px;line-height: 1px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;display: none;max-width: 0px;max-height: 0px;opacity: 0;overflow: hidden;mso-hide:all;">
                Start
            </div> -->

            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table width="800" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="color:#1C1E23;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
            <![endif]-->

            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation"
                style="color:#111111; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: #006c5e; Margin:0; padding:0; width: 100%; max-width: 800px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>

                        <!-- Main Message -->
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation"
                            style="Margin: 0; padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 40px 40px 40px 40px;">
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                        style="Margin: 0; padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>

                                                <!-- header of list -->
                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td
                                                            style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 700; line-height: 31.2px; color: #FFFFFF;word-break: break-word; padding: 24px 0 24px 0;">
                                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet:
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <!-- End header of list -->

                                                <!-- template -->
                                                <table width="100%" border="0"
                                                    cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding: 0 0 24px 0;">
                                                            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0"
                                                                    cellpadding="0">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                                                                            <table width=" 100%" border="0"
                                                                                cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="212"
                                                                                        style="max-width: 212px; padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;">
                                                                                        <img width="212" height="157"
                                                                                            src="#"
                                                                                            alt="photo"
                                                                                            style="display: block; object-fit: cover;">
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td
                                                                                        style="vertical-align: top; padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px; text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400;line-height: 140%; color: #333333; ">
                                                                                        <div
                                                                                            style="height: 157px; overflow-y: hidden;">
                                                                                            <p
                                                                                                style="Margin: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; line-height: 28.8px; color: #006c5e;">
                                                                                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                                                                                            </p>
                                                                                            <p id="some-text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet
                                                                                                consectetur adipisicing
                                                                                                elit. Cupiditate accusantium
                                                                                                et voluptatibus ullam, fuga
                                                                                                optio beatae officia aliquam
                                                                                                aperiam in sint veritatis
                                                                                                dolorum error quae minima
                                                                                                iste. Explicabo dolorum
                                                                                                temporibus laudantium fugiat
                                                                                                ducimus reprehenderit
                                                                                                provident beatae dolorem,
                                                                                                repellat ad esse in cumque!
                                                                                                Quibusdam minus possimus
                                                                                                assumenda, iste ea dolore
                                                                                                veniam at ipsam iusto
                                                                                                molestias, veritatis
                                                                                                maiores? Iusto, tempore rem
                                                                                                perferendis deserunt quis
                                                                                                cum dolor quo sit omnis?
                                                                                                Eaque ea incidunt
                                                                                                voluptatibus nihil
                                                                                                architecto dolores rem
                                                                                                facilis omnis tempora ab
                                                                                                optio accusamus aperiam, cum
                                                                                                corporis dolorem beatae nemo
                                                                                                quidem tempore? Fugit
                                                                                                quisquam nobis vero quo
                                                                                                atque consequatur maxime,
                                                                                                sunt non, impedit quia
                                                                                                possimus magnam ab illo nemo
                                                                                                vitae ipsum. Eligendi at
                                                                                                ipsa id iste beatae. Quidem
                                                                                                nemo enim similique ex,
                                                                                                repellat omnis debitis nisi
                                                                                                ipsam fugit iusto incidunt
                                                                                                unde magnam, voluptate animi
                                                                                                veniam dolorum consectetur
                                                                                                doloribus sapiente eaque
                                                                                                eum. Cum quia facilis atque
                                                                                                earum perspiciatis aperiam
                                                                                                eos, alias et ullam
                                                                                                officiis?</p>
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </table>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <!-- End Template -->

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- End Main message -->

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
             <![endif]-->

        </div>
    </center>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried classes, specifying the height in the class, and inline style.
I also tried to set the height for the table elements.

```
<table width="800" border="0" cellspasing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout: fixed; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-collapse: collapse; ">
    <tr>
        <td style="position: relative; max-height: 157px; height: 157px; overflow-y: hidden;">
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block; max-height: 157px; height: 157px; overflow-y: hidden;">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try to use the following methods for limiting the height of the table cell in outlook.**

- You can set a fixed height on the  element containing `#some-text` and use the CSS property overflow to hide or scroll the extra content.

`<td style="height: 100px; overflow: hidden;">...</td>`

or you can use
`<td style="height: 100px; overflow: scroll;">...</td>`

- **You can use min-height and max-height properties to define an absolute height for the table cell.** Just keep in mind that support for these in Outlook is limited and might not work as you might expect them to.
- **You can use a nested table.** Place the content inside a nested table with a fixed height to constrain the content within that height.
  Conditional Comments: Use Microsoft Outlook conditional comments to apply styles specifically for Outlook.

You could also use Outlook's Conditional comments to apply styles to the emails. Like this:

```
<!--[if mso]>
<td style="height: 100px;">
<![endif]-->
```

You can replace the content with an image, meaning if the content is not dynamic, you can put an image inside the table cell to represent the content, since images do not expand the cell height.

**Try to remember that Outlook’s rendering engine can be quite different from web browsers, and it’s known to have limited CSS support. Testing across different versions of Outlook is crucial to ensure compatibility. Additionally, you can use tools like Litmus or Email on Acid to preview how your email will look in various email clients, including different versions of Outlook.**

Comment: Your advice is good, but not my situation(
Unfortunately, it's not work for my example

Answer (score 0):

Tables are designed to expand to the height needed to fit the content. That's why to limit it for everything else, you need the div.

For Outlook, you can use VML. It does change that portion into an image, however, so you lose out certain functions like the ability to copy the text, or with accessibility (screenreaders will not be able to read the text).

This has been tested in Outlook desktop and Gmail webmail:

```
<!--[if mso]>
                    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" style="height:100px;width:200px;" stroke="false" fill="true" fillcolor="#ff0000" alt="" role="presentation">
                    <w:anchorlock/>
                    <![endif]-->
                        <div style="overflow-y: hidden;max-height: 100px;">
                            <p>Happy Friday! Have you ever wanted to strike up a convo with a robot? Well, now you can: This week, Figure AI implemented OpenAI’s tech into its Figure 01 robot. In the same way that ChatGPT can now speak aloud, this humanoid robot can too…while performing physical actions like picking up trash and putting away dishes (no, seriously). While it’s not yet commercially available, I’m predicting a multitasking, chatty robot on every holiday gift guide in 2025.   </p>
                        </div>
                    <!--[if mso]>
                    </v:rect>
                <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Your solution is very interesting.
It's works for me.

Comment: Is it possible to add a colon `...` in the place where the text is cut off?

Comment: No, unfortunately you can't